# How to make a L-shape layout with Row and Column?

Tags: flutter, layout

I would like to make the following layout within a Card widget (card within Sized Box to control the height):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLinu.png]

layout description is:

- Blue : height: same as Card's height, width: fixed
- Green: height: fixed, width: remaining width of the card
- Purple: height: remaining height of the card, width: fixed
- Pink: height: remaining height of the card, width: remaining width of the card

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are looking for is below

```
SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(width: 100,color: Colors.blue),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(height: 30,color: Colors.green,),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(width: 100,color: Colors.purple),
                              Expanded(child:
                              Container(color: Colors.pinkAccent),)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )

                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Output

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

This will work regardless of the height/width available (it is responsive).

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 7 / 2,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          const Flexible(
            flex: 2,
            child: SizedBox.expand(
              child: ColoredBox(color: Colors.blue),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 5,
            child: SizedBox.expand(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: ColoredBox(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: SizedBox.expand(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 4,
                    child: Row(
                      children: const [
                        Flexible(
                          flex: 3,
                          child: SizedBox.expand(
                            child: ColoredBox(color: Colors.purple),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          flex: 4,
                          child: SizedBox.expand(
                            child: ColoredBox(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 249, 139, 176)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:
[image: Output]